# DRF ViewSet always returns HTTP 200

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to DRF.

This is my ViewSet (which is based on [this example](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#example) of official documentation of DRF):

```
class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        serializer = AccountSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, email=None):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        user = get_object_or_404(queryset, email=email)
        serializer = AccountSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I have two email addresses in the database.

My API client is `httpie`.

When I send a `GET` request to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/accounts/` I get back those two emails. So this part works fine.

However, when I provide an email address that doesn't exits in the database (as `Params` or `Headers`), I again get those two emails instead of `404`.

I did a little bit of research and change the code like this:

```
class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        serializer = AccountSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, email=None):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        try:
            user = get_object_or_404(queryset, email=email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=404)
        serializer = AccountSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Again, `200` with those two emails.

Even when I provide an email that **does** exists, I get both in response.

I can't figure out what I'm missing.

P.S: My URL patterns is defined as below:

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from .views import AccountViewSet

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'accounts', AccountViewSet, basename='accounts')

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Comment: I think `retrieve` is getting called when you pass the email to url like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/accounts/<email>`

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM Thanks. I get Django's Page not found error when I open ```http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/accounts/me@email.com```.  I've added my URL patterns to my post.

Answer (score 2):

`email` is not defined as a keyword argument in the URL routing, so the `retrieve` method is never called when you try to GET a single user by `email`.

You should either (**solution 1**) override the `lookup_field` definition on the `ViewSet` level:

```py
class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    # The rest of the code is kept intact

    lookup_field = "email"
```

---

Or (**solution 2**) define a custom `route`/`action` in your `ViewSet` (and then you that `route`/`action` instead of `retrieve`):

```py
from rest_framework.decorators import action

class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    # The rest of the code is kept intact

    @action(detail=False, methods=["GET"])
    def get_by_email(self, request):
        email = request.query_params.get("email", None)
        if email is None:
            return Response(status=400, data={"message": "Email parameter is required"})

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=404)

        serializer = AccountSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

---

Alternatively (**solution 3**), you could define the URL patterns as follows:

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import AccountViewSet

urlpatterns = [
    path("accounts/", AccountViewSet.as_view({"get": "list"}), name="account-list"),
    path("accounts/<str:email>/", AccountViewSet.as_view({"get": "retrieve"}), name="account-detail"),
]
```

Comment: Thanks. First solution works if the email is wrong, but if the email is correct I get Django's standard 404 error.